# Why is equality of left derivative and right derivative just a sufficient condition?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We know that for derivability, continuity is a necessary condition and equality of left derivative and right derivative is a sufficient condition. Since equality of left derivative and right derivative is a sufficient condition, so if it is true, then it implies that the function is derivable. But I think that it is also a necessary condition, it's because if a function is derivable, then it also implies equality of left derivative and right derivative.

A point on a function is derivable if and only if left derivative and right derivative are the same.

But why is it just a sufficient condition?

Comment: If you take $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$, then $f$ is differentiable at $0$. However, you don't have equality of left derivative and right derivative, since there is no left derivative.